# Import data from Excel to database using java and javascript. What's the faster way?

Tags: javascript, java, excel, parsing, import

I want to import data from excel with a lot of records (thousands records). I think we can use javascript to prepare data and then insert to database, or another way is upload excel file and use java to process after that.
What's the faster way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a general answer like "Use JS cause then it's faster!".

This highly depends on your implementation and of course on the resources of the server....

I'd upload it, and process it on the server side with java. There are really good frameworks to process excel in Java (https://poi.apache.org/)

All the best